# How to update a nested dictionary in DolphinDB?

Tags: dictionary, nested-attributes, dolphindb

I'm trying to update values within a nested dictionary in DolphinDB, as shown in the following scipt:

```
d1 = dict( STRING, ANY )
d2 = dict( STRING, ANY )

d2[`d2_K] = 1
d1[`d1_K] = d2
d2[`d2_K] = 3
```

But an error occurs: `Syntax Error: [line #1] Cannot recognize the token objAddress`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an intermediate variable for assignment:

```
tmp = d1[`d1_K]
tmp[`d2_K]=3
d1[`d1_K]=tmp
```